# Discord.js Bot Replying to All Commands

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js to create a "text-adventure" bot. The user chooses what they would like to do by replying a, b, c, or d. I have separated the questions by using a variable called "stage". The problem is, the bot does not let the user choose the next choice, but instead uses their previous answer.

I tried using .lastMessage, but I either couldn't get it to work. That or I had been using it wrong, as I am a bit of an amateur.

Below is a bit of code to show you how I handled it. (I removed the story as it got a bit...violent)

```
require("dotenv").config();

var stage = 0;
let time = 0;
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`${client.user.username} has arrived`);
}); 

client.on('message', (message) => {

if (message.author.bot === true) return;


if (message.content === 'begin') {
    
    }
if (message.content === 'restart'){
    stage = 0;
    message.channel.send('Welcome adventurer! To begin, type "a"');
}
    if (message.content === 'a' && stage === 0) {
       
        message.channel.send('...');
        message.channel.send('...');
        message.channel.send('...');
        message.channel.send('Do you:');
        message.channel.send('a) ...');
        message.channel.send('b) ...');
        message.channel.send('c) ...');
        message.channel.send('d) ...');

        stage = 1;
        
        }
        if (message.content === 'a' && stage === 1) {
            message.channel.send('...');
            message.channel.send('...);
            message.channel.send('...');
            message.channel.send('...');
            message.channel.send('...');
            message.channel.send('Do you:');
            message.channel.send('a) ...');
            message.channel.send('b) ...');

        }    
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORDJS_BOT_TOKEN);
```

EDIT: Sorry I didn't add that much code, I am unfamiliar with this website, and added the rest. The bot itself works, I'm just not sure how to make it only respond to one message once.

I used this video if you need more info:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmKXBVdEV0g&t=15s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia

Comment: Could you add a bit more to your code to show which section specifically is not working?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I added some more code to better explain. If needed, I can include some screenshots too.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your first message.content check block, your code sets `stage = 1;`. Then it immediately evaluates the next message.content && stage check as true, because you just set stage to 1. Try:

```
       } else if (message.content === 'a' && stage === 1) {
```

or use a switch/case statement. You could also `return;` right after  `stage = 1;`. Here is a simplified example:

```js
var stage = 0;

function client_on(message) {
  if (message.content === 'a' && stage === 0) {
    //...
    console.log(stage,message.content);
    stage = 1;
    //Return here, or else the next block will evaluate to true
    return; 
  }
  if (message.content === 'a' && stage === 1) {
    //...
    console.log(stage,message.content);
    stage = 2;
    //Return here also, if you have more checks to run
    return; 
  }
}

client_on({content:'a'});
console.log('next message');
client_on({content:'a'});
```

Also, your entire code logic could just be represented as a data structure like:

```
var storyMap = new Map([
  ['0restart', 'Welcome adventurer! To begin, type "a"'],
  ['1a', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
  ['1b', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
  ['1c', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
  ['1d', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
  ['2a', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
  ['2b', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
  ['2c', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
  ['2d', '...\nDo you:\na)...\nb)...\nc)...\nd)...'],
]);

client.on('message', (message) => {
   var key = stage.toString() + message.content;
   var response = storyMap.get(key);
   if (response) {
     message.channel.send(response);
     stage++;
   } else {
     message.channel.send('error, try again');
   }
}
```